# Missing partial with Mailboxer Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

I follow this tutorial to add a messagerie in y rails project.

All seems fine but I click on the "Sent link" There is an error with the partial message.

```
Missing partial mailbox/_messages, application/_messages with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
* "/Users/baptiste/code/BaptisteB/bosszzd/app/views"
  * "/Users/baptiste/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mailboxer-0.13.0/app/views"
  * "/Users/baptiste/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/app/views"
```

I don't really understand, here some code :

Show#view

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-body">
       <%= render partial: 'messages' %>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the partial _messages.html.erb

```
<% @receipts.each do |receipt| %>
    <% message = receipt.message %>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left">
        <!-- user avators can go here -->
        <a href="#">
          <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="...">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
          <%= message.sender.first_name %> <%= message.sender.last_name[0] %> <br>
          <small><b>Subject: </b><%= message.subject %></small><br>
          <small><b>Date: </b><%=  message.created_at.strftime("%A, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M%p") %></small>
        </h4>
        <%= message.body %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I place the partial _messages.html.erb in `app/views/conversations/_messages.htm.erb`

Thank you for your help

The path of the **Sent link** is mailbox_sent                              `GET      /mailbox/sent(.:format)                       mailbox#sent`

and the link is

```
<li class="<%= active_page(:sent) %>">
    <%= link_to mailbox_sent_path do %>
```

Here is conversations controller

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @receipts = Receipt.all
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    recipients = User.where(id: conversation_params[:recipients])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, conversation_params[:body], conversation_params[:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Your message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def show
    @receipts = conversation.receipts_for(current_user)
    # mark conversation as read
    conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)
  end

  def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, message_params[:body])
    flash[:notice] = "Your reply message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def trash
    conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

  def untrash
    conversation.untrash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end


  private

  def conversation_params
    params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject, :body, recipients:[])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :subject)
  end
end
```

MailboxController

```
class MailboxController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def inbox
    @inbox = mailbox.inbox
    @active = :inbox
  end

  def sent
    @sent = mailbox.sentbox
    @active = :sent
  end

  def trash
    @trash = mailbox.trash
    @active = :trash
  end

end
```

Conversations Controller

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!



  def new
  end

  def create
    recipients = User.where(id: conversation_params[:recipients])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, conversation_params[:body], conversation_params[:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Your message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def show
    @receipts = conversation.receipts_for(current_user)
    # mark conversation as read
    conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)
  end

  def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, message_params[:body])
    flash[:notice] = "Your reply message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def trash
    conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

  def untrash
    conversation.untrash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end


  private

  def conversation_params
    params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject, :body, recipients:[])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :subject)
  end
end
```

The view is `<%= render partial: 'mailbox/folder_view', locals: { is_conversation: false, messages: @inbox } %>`

The partial folder is

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="<%= active_page(:inbox) %>">
    <%= link_to mailbox_inbox_path do  %>
        <span class="label label-danger pull-right"><%=unread_messages_count%></span>
        <em class="fa fa-inbox fa-lg"></em>
        <span>Inbox</span>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= active_page(:sent) %>">
    <%= link_to mailbox_sent_path do %>

        <em class="fa fa-paper-plane-o fa-lg"></em>
        <span>Sent</span>
    <% end %>
  </li>

  <li class="<%= active_page(:trash) %>">
    <%= link_to mailbox_trash_path do %>
        <em class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></em>
        <span>Trash</span>
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you just specify the path of your view template in which you have the **Sent link**  and where you have placed the **_messages.html.erb** partial.

Comment: @dpk I post above what you aked

Comment: `<%= render 'conversations/messages' %>` - Have you tried changing your partial rendering like this ?

Comment: I tried and now the error is 'undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass'  for the iteration in the partial '_messages.html.erb'

Comment: have you defined `@receipts` anywhere in your controller or not ? This error says `each` method is being operated on an undefined object i.e `@receipts` as it is only mentioned in your partial.

Comment: just define in my Conversations controller. I pasted it above.

Comment: can you please paste the complete error log now ?

Comment: which controller and action you have used to render your views ?

Comment: I send you the explanation above

Comment: You need to define `@receipts` in your `MailboxController` `sent` action.   Just put `@receipts = Receipt.all` inside  `MailboxController` `sent` action

Comment: How do I do? Because I did it here                                                                `def index
   @receipts = Receipt.all
 end`

Comment: I think when you hit **Sent link**, it takes to  `MailboxController` `sent` action as your path suggests `GET      /mailbox/sent(.:format)                       mailbox#sent`

Comment: Hey @dpk I am doing all steps one by one and I come to you to say if it is that. See you in a moment.

Comment: Hey @dpk I have this error when I put the partial `_messages.html.erb`= `The action 'index' could not be found for ConversationsController`

Comment: The issue seems to be that it is looking for _messages in `mailbox/_messages` when you actually want it to be looking in `conversations/messages`. Have you tried doing `<%= render partial: "conversations/messages"` ?