# Create a Messenger Sender Receiver with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Who knows a Tuto or a link I can follow to create an intern messenger with a Ruby app.

I tried some tutos nothing work. I don't really understand.
Just want to show a view and get a space to send an receive message and trash them. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also, Sendgrid => **https://github.com/stephenb/sendgrid**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `rails mailboxer gem` https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer

Here is a tutorial http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/private-inbox-system-in-rails-with-mailboxer

Comment: hey Thank you I did this Tuto  twice Time and I have A Missing Template error. Thhat's why I would like to know if there is an other way.

Comment: Oh, interesting. What is your missing template error, maybe someone can help you to solve that issue?

Comment: Hey :) here is my problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374798/missing-partial-with-mailboxer-gem?noredirect=1#comment60368837_36374798) but noboby has solved this. And I contact directly Joseph. You can checked the last comment I think. Have you tried? Could I check your repository :)

Comment: But I have a problem with the partial `conversations/_conversations.html.erb`

Comment: have you taken a look on it?